# Problema para acceder a la geolocalización en nw.js

Tags: javascript

Quisiera saber cómo se puede acceder a la geolocalización en [nw.js](http://nwjs.io/). Estoy intentando y me arroja el siguiente mensaje cuando uso el método `watchPosition` o el método `getCurrentPosition`:

> Network location provider at 'https://www.googleapis.com/' : Returned error code 400

Comment: Puedes agregar tu codigo actual a tu pregunta, asi sera mas facil para todos ver que es lo que esta sucediendo

Comment: Parece que hay un [bug abierto para un error similar en su página de github](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/236) (en inglés). Se menciona algo sobre que se necesita una Google API key y que funciona sólo para Win8+ y OSX. Pero es un hilo de hace 3-4 meses